# Variable not printing in console.log

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I have large chunk of js code.
I am not able to display the output in `console.log`.
Can you tell me what I am missing?
I am providing my code below:

```
var multCoffees = false;
if (Coffees.length > 1) {
    multCoffees = true;
}
if (apptTimeCell) {
    apptTimeHTML = MyDay.dish(allData, multCoffees);
    apptTimeCell.innerHTML = apptTimeHTML;
} else {
    apptTimeCell = Util.cep("span", {
        className: "appt-time"
    });
    patientRowTD.insertBefore(apptTimeCell, patCell);
}
dish: function (allData, multCoffees) {
    if (multCoffees) {
        var htmlArr = [];
        htmlArr.push(allData.APPT_TIME_DISPLAY, "<br/><span class='sub-detail'>", allData.MNEMONIC, "</span>");
        console.log("multiCoffee" + allData.PROVIDER_MNEMONIC);
        return htmlArr.join("");
    } else {
        return allData.APPT_TIME_DISPLAY;
    }
},
```

Comment: So, what *does* your code do?  Do you see an error?  Does the rest of the code work?

Comment: Where are you using the "delegate" function? Please provide a fiddle.

Comment: @andrew `.delegate()` is jquery's old way of using `.on()`

Comment: is it possible to call this functions using an id...if so how..

Comment: @user2565289: Which function?  What ID?  What do you want to do?  Can you answer my previous questions?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to have the ** around your console statement?  That is probably causing the error.

```
**console.log("dateRaj" + date);**
```

Comment: My guess is he was trying to **bold** that line in the code block.

Comment: i am not able to see my console.log values

Comment: @user2565289: What does that mean?  What *do* you see?  Are there errors?  We need more info to be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

I know this behaviour. This happens when combining values with strings ( especially with objects). Try to output your data variable stand alone without combining it with the string. This way:

```
console.log("dateRaj");
console.log(date);
```

**update**
Like my commentators said the console seems to take also multiple arguments which may be the most elegant way to go.

Comment: why not just use multiple arguments? `console.log("dateRaj", date, x, y, z);` if the var is undefined or anything, it will be an empty string.

Comment: Or he can also `console.log("dateRaj", date);`

Comment: is it possible to call this functions using an id...if so how..

Comment: Separated be comma sounds plausible. I didn't know that console can be used with multiple elements. Thanks for this hint guys!

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing...

With `unescapeJSON()` you mean `JSON.parse()` ?

Show us your syntax error message?

Comment: the function which i commented out is throwing the error...

Comment: @user2565289: What error?  Can you show us the *exact* error you see?